# How in Object Pascal find whether a character is alphanumeric or underscore working in both Delphi compiler and FPC?

Tags: compilation, freepascal, alphanumeric, delphi

There are similar or same questions all over the internet, but the answers don't work for me. We develop multiplatform product, which is compiled both under Delphi's compiler and under FPC. 
First, I used:

```
Uses:
  System.Character;
```

and

```
Character.TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit(..)
```

, but it couldn't be compiled under FPC, so according to some other source, I used:

```
Uses:
  Character;
```

and

```
TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit(..)
```

instead, but still can't be compiled under FPC.

Can someone find a way that the code will work on both Delphi compiler and FPC? I don't have FPC set up to work with my project, so I can't figure out on my own, how to fix the code to work in FPC (I can test it only in complicated way via build server) and can't find a way, how to do it.

I also wanted to write it using regex, but colleagues say, that it would be too complicated for them.

Comment: I would make my own function in separate unit and use `{$IFDEF FPC}` to branch between Delphi and FPC implementation.

Comment: Yes, I would use something like if (<char> in ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_']), but colleagues say, that there must be some function that does it more neatly (and can be reusable on more places). I care only about the ASCII btw. And I don't want to create a new function, because I really think that it's already written.

Comment: You didn't understand what Victoria said. Your new function doesn't do the grunk work. It just calls the library methods of Delphi and FPC, conditionally. In doing so it presents a platform independent interface.

Comment: Aha, sry, ok, I can conditionally do it also outside new function, but I don't know how to correctly call in from FPC, because the compilation always fails.

Comment: Anyway, you don't need to do it conditionally at all. You can use `TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit` in both. Now some harsh advice. Don't ever ask about errors without giving the details of the error. "can't be compiled" is really no help to anybody. Perhaps you don't read error messages, but we do. And if you don't, you need to learn how to read them right away.

Comment: Please name versions(My Delphi doesn't have an unit character.) and what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, I just set up FPC anyway to try it and following code worked, so I guess that our buildservers have some strange configuration: 
Program test;
uses Character;
var
text: ansiString;
begin
  text := 'whatever';
  TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit(text), 1);
end.

Comment: Any time something *"can't be compiled"*, please, please include the error messages.

Comment: @Marco: which Delphi is that? AFAICT, XE2 up to Tokyo have a unit `Character` or `System.Character`. The class is `TCharacter`. It only has class methods. The unit also contains a number of global functions. The FPC version I use (3.0) also has such a unit, which looks very much the same.

Comment: @Rudy, [that's what came to mind immediately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlRLfbONYgM&feature=youtu.be&t=1m11s) :)

Comment: @Victoria: I'm afraid I don't get it.

Comment: @Rudy, I think that EMBT could "borrow" something from FPC as well in time ([quid pro quo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo)). And you're a doctor :)

Comment: Sry to all, because it always worked on my PC, but didn't work on our buildserver and I don't know, how is it run on it.

Comment: Well, this was D7, something a customer uses to keep his HMI's running. The Delphi version is also important for things like System.Character and just Character (XE2 introduced that?), so D2009,2010 and XE have just character too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Delphi and FPC include a class named `TCharacter` which exposes a method named `IsLetterOrDigit`. In other words, the premise of your question is wrong. It is perfectly reasonable to use `TCharacter.IsLetterOrDigit`.

Documentation links:

- Delphi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharacter
- FPC: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/rtl/character/tcharacter.html

It's entirely possible that you are using an out of date version of FPC, which would explain why your code fails. Although that is guesswork since you did not include any details of the error message.

Comment: I realized, that our buildservers have some strange configuration and I did it different way, like <Char> in ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_'], because my colleagues don't want to use TCharacter anyway and this is lesser evil. Thanks.

Comment: The `in ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_']` expression will not work properly in Delphi, as in Delphi, Char is mapped to WideChar, and sets can only contain 0..255 values, hence no WideChars. Use `TCharacter` instead, no matter if your colleagues, for some unknown reason, don't want to use it.

Comment: FWIW, `Tcharacter ... deprecated 'Use TCharHelper';` in XE7 help, did not check earlier.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: it may be deprecated, but it still works, and TCharHelper probably won't work in FPC.

Comment: FPC trunk supports value type helpers. Maybe even 3.0 does.HelperBut the RTL support usually lags

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In the end, I used "CharInSet(<AnsiChar>, ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_'])" and it works well and without warnings/hints.